# EXCEL - SUMIF for multiple sheets

Tags: excel, sumifs

I need to sum a range of cells in several sheets if another range of cells for each sheet match a criteria. The formula is as shown below.

```
=SUMIF('sheet0'!D3:Q3; "x"; 'sheet0'!D9:P9)+SUMIF('sheet1'!D3:Q3; "x"; sheet1'!D9:P9)+SUMIF('sheet2'!D3:Q3; "x"; 'sheet2'!D9:P9)
```

While, this does work correctly, I need to do this for more than **50 sheets** and I'd like to know if is a way to write a shorter formula to get the same result.

Comment: I would be looking at a summary sheet, using cells for the sumif() for each sheet, but use indirect() to build the reference so I can set up a list of names as the cell range seems to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

the Criteria range & sum range must have same range

Your Formula :

```
SUMIF('sheet0'!D3:Q3; "x"; 'sheet0'!D9:P9)
```

it won't work because Criteria Range starts from D to Q but the sum range starts from D to P.

Try to fix it to this:

```
SUMIF('sheet0'!D3:P3; "x"; 'sheet0'!D9:P9)
```